# Add "Rarity-Frequence" with actionscript/flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, frequency

I'm making a small actionscript game where one objects has to fly to dodge certain objects. Now I have all objects made but the problem is that the appear all as frequently. And I want that the smaller objects ( like a leaf ) appear more frequent then let's say a tree branch.

Also we have a small bonus in the game that adds extra life and that should not happen as frequent as a leaf or a branch but should happen very little.

How can I make this work in actionscript?

This is for example the code of a leaf appearing on screen.

import flash.events.Event;

```
var movement = 10;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
function update(e:Event) {
    x = x - movement; 
    movement = movement + 0.04;
    if (x < -width) {
        x = stage.stageWidth + width;
        y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So its a side scroller from right to left, the objects are accelerating at the same rate and you want some things to be generated in a higher quantity than others.

The code you provided has no linkage to your question.

You have a function that generates objects, right? add another parameter that is between 0 and 1, lets call it frequency.

Do a test, each time you generate an object: if( Math.random() > frequency ) then you generate object.

For the leaves, put 1, so you have 100% of possible leaves generated. For the branches, put 0.2 So you have 20%, or one 5th of the possible branches generated.

If you want a cap of objects, then put 0.8 to leaves and 0.2 to branches, so from all 100% objects, 80% are leaves, 20% are branches.

Comment: Ok I will try that and sorry for providing the wrong function I thought it had to be coded in there.

Comment: Ok so what you told me worked fine, but now the problem I have is that once it has past the first frequency, it shows up as fast. So somehow I should "RESET" this...

Comment: do a movement = 10 when you want to, I assume at the beginning of each level.

Comment: That's not the problem, sorry I may have explained it wrong. Somehow I should do a "removeChild" of the object as soon as it exits the frame because when it is added to the stage it stays there.

Comment: remove it when its mySprite.x <= -mySprite.width, that should be enough.

Comment: you can recycle destroyed leaves by moving them from the left out of bounds back to the right spawn area, thus eliminating useless removeChild / addChild calls. These are quite taxing. Unless you remove leaves in other events other than your of bounds.

Comment: Ok everything is working now! Thank you for your fast and easy help!